# Edit textView child from ExpandableListView (Strikethrough)

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a `ExpandableListView` with a `OnChildClickListener` but how can I add strikethrough to the `TextView` when it is clicked?

mExpandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Group: " + groupPosition + " Child: " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Do something (i.e. add strikethourgh) to the TextView clicked..

            return false;
        }
    });
```

My layout file for the activity is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calc_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/calc_expandable_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

</LinearLayout>
```

while the children of the ExpandableList is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_text_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The error from LogCat is:

```
W/dalvikvm(28424): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0) E/AndroidRuntime(28424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(28424): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout E/AndroidRuntime(28424):     at com.test.skylderhverandre.Calc$1.onChildClick(Calc.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:527)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(28424):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) like this :

```
CharSequence value = ((TextView)((LinearLayout)v).getChildAt(0)).getText();
if(value!=null){
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(value);
    spannableString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, value.length(), 0);
    ((TextView)((LinearLayout)v).getChildAt(0)).setText(spannableString);
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but it get an error at the first line. Cant get the child textview, I think..

Comment: maybe take care of null value. (see edit)
I don't think this can be called with a null `v`. (put a breakpoint to see what's going wrong)

Comment: I tried to step through, but the first line fails. (Bore anything is returned).
Added xml-code in my question, if that can be of interest..

Comment: you must have something in your logcat, please post it

Comment: Error posted. I appreciate you help, @ben75! :)

Comment: You just have to find the textView inside the linearlayout. (see my edit)